# POST data to a Google form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-docs

I am trying to post data to a from AJAX to a Google form, but even though it reports success with a statusCode of 0, the data never appears in the form:

```
var dat={ "entry.529474552" :"data1", "entry.1066559787": "name1"};
postToGoogle("1FAIpQLSf4w1OQGsIncaiqXlmfAl4jYSt-e4Zx3xVJa7Weob4LnQbRZQ",dat);

function postToGoogle(id, dat) {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'chrome-extension://EXTENSION_ID');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT');
            },
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/"+id+"/formResponse",
        data: dat, 
        type: "POST",  
        dataType: "xml",
        xhrFields: {  withCredentials: true },
        statusCode: {
            0:   function() {  console.log("OK") },
            200: function() {  console.log("error") },
            }
        });
    }
```

It generates a CORS error, but supposedly, the POST should go through anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**For those looking to do this as of April 2019**

I was working on this today. The current answer is as follows:

Each field in the Google Form has a unique ID. In order to retrieve it, get a pre-filled link by filling out all relevant form fields you wish to programatically submit

**Note:** In order to ensure the URL is accessible without restriction, you'll also want to disable restriction to your domain only **(for GSuite paying users)**

[image: Google Forms Interface]

Then, copy the link and paste in your browser. The URL has a base format as follows:

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/[FORMID]/formResponse

Each param is a key/value pair of type: entry.XXXXXX=value

The prefilled link will give you the value of XXXXX for each relevant field

Request must be made with following headers:

**Method:** GET

**Content-Type:** application/x-www-form-urlencoded

The final request looks like this

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/123332233bsj333/formResponse?entry.123456=value1&entry.2333442=value2&submit=Submit

**Don't forget to append submit=Submit at the end of your request!**

Comment: getting CORS error for the GET request, (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing), any way to fix this?

Comment: I haven't personally run into this issue, so can't help you there. You may want to check Mozilla's documentation around CORs errors.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors

Also, it would be useful for another answerer if you could provide a code snippet et better background on the stack used

Comment: @NitinSawant 
You can just send `mode` with `no-cors` value, see my fetch config
```
fetch(formData, {
          method: 'GET',
          mode: 'no-cors', // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
          cache: 'no-cache',
          credentials: 'omit', // include, *same-origin, omit
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
        })
```
formData is just whole URL

Comment: that is the best way of getting the entry.XXXXXX names. Most tutorials have you going through the inspect element.

Answer (score 2):

> It generates a CORS error, but supposedly, the POST should go through anyway.

While it is possible to make a successful POST request, get a CORS error, and be unable to read the response, this is only true for Simple Requests.

Because your request has:

- Custom headers (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, which are **response** headers and have no business being on a request in the first place)
- Credentials (i.e. you have set `withCredentials: true`)

… it is a Preflighted Request.

Before the browser will make the POST request, it will make an OPTIONS request to ask permission.

Since it doesn't get permission, the request fails.

---

Note that even if you did turn it into a simple request and make the POST successfully, you would still get a status of `0`. You can't read the status when there is a CORS error.

Comment: hmmm. If I don't put in at least the headers, I get a 404 error: 
Failed to load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1FAIpQLSf4w1OQGsIncaiqXlmfAl4jYSt-e4Zx3xVJa7Weob4LnQbRZQ/formResponse: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I did get it to work as you suggested without the preflight request, but needed to modify the url to include a /e/ to the path (edited in original request). ie:     url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/"+id+"/formResponse",